# table data and column type (react-table v8)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-table

I am fairly new to typescript, I am using `@tanstack/react-table` and built a `TableComponent` around the `useReactTable` hook, it takes 2 props `data` and `columns` and passes them to the `useReactTable` hook.

The problem is that the data and columns props are arrays that can contain different types of objects and they are connected, how can I type them correctly? Right now I am getting an error inside the `TableComponent`

```
type OrderTableProps = {
  data: OrdersRow[];
  columns: typeof ordersTableColumns;
  onRowClick?: (row: Row<OrdersRow>) => void;
}

type ContainerTableProps = {
  data: ContainersRow[];
  columns: typeof containersTableColumns;
  onRowClick?: (row: Row<ContainersRow>) => void;
}

export type TableComponentProps = PropsWithChildren
  & TableComponentBaseProps
  & (OrderTableProps | ContainerTableProps);
    

// TableComponent
    const ReactTableComponent = ({data, columns}: TableComponentProps) => {
     const table = useReactTable({
        data, -> Type 'OrdersRow[] | ContainersRow[]' is not assignable to type 'OrdersRow[]'
        columns,
        getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(),
      });
    
      return (
        <Table> ... </Table>
```

}

Answer (score 5):

What you need is a Table component with generic types. Let's do it.

For example, the table component name is **ReactTable**. First, we define the interface, so our table can receive any data and columns provided.

```
import {
  ColumnDef,
  useReactTable,
  ...
} from "@tanstack/react-table";

interface ReactTableProps<TData> {
  data: TData[];
  columns: ColumnDef<TData>[];
}

const ReactTable = <TData extends object>({
  data,
  columns,
}: ReactTableProps<TData>) => {
  const table = useReactTable({
    data,
    columns,
    getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(),
  });

  return (
    ...
  )
}
```

And then, we can implement our table as follow:

```
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ReactTable data={orders} columns={orderColumns} />
      <ReactTable data={containers} columns={containerColumns} />
    </div>
  );
```

And if you want to be more strict, you can implement the types as follows:

```
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ReactTable<Order> data={orders} columns={orderColumns} />
      <ReactTable<Container> data={containers} columns={containerColumns} />
    </div>
  );
```

You can see the complete code here:

[image: Edit beautiful-currying-ih7vmi]